# Have there been efforts to prevent length extension attacks of hashing algorithms that are based on the Merkle–Damgård construction?

Tags: hash, merkle-damgaard, length-extension

Have there ever been some publicized efforts to prevent length extension attacks of hashing algorithms that are based on the Merkle–Damgård construction (MD5, SHA1, SHA2, ...)?

Comment: Double-Hashing and truncation?

Comment: HMAC is the typical construction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In this [paper](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2005/36210424/36210424.pdf), Coron and al. showed that a plain MD construction is secure when it's inputs are prefix-free. They actually proved the indifferentiability of the construction. In other words messages need to be encoded in a prefix-free manner.

Quoting the paper:

> A prefix-free code over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}^κ$is an efficiently computable injective function $g: \{0, 1\}^∗ \to (\{0, 1\}^κ)^∗$such that for all $x \neq y$, $g(x)$ is not a
>   prefix of $g(y)$.

One such encoding is given in the paper

> **Function g1(m)**: let $N$ be the message length of $m$ in bits.
>   write $m$ as $(m_1, \ldots , m_l)$ where for all $i$, $|m_i| = k$.
>   and with the last block $m_l$ padded with $10^r$.
>   let $g1(m) = (\langle N \rangle, m_1, \ldots , m_l)$ where $\langle N \rangle$ is a $κ$-bit binary encoding of $N$.

Answer (score 3):

- Fixed output filters like SHA-256d
- Keyed output filters like HMAC, envelope-MAC, *etc.*
- Truncation like SHA-512/256
- Prefix-free message encoding like length-prefixed
- Non-MD designs like BLAKE2 with HAIFA, SHA-3 with a sponge